# Nested foreach-loop only working once on PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

This is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php 
$kategorien = $kategorieQuery
$items = $itemQuery
foreach($kategorien as $kategorie): ?>
    <div class="list">
        <h1><?php echo $kategorie['kategorie']; ?></h1>
        <?php if(!empty($items)): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($items as $item):
                if($kategorie['kategorie'] == $item['kategorie']): ?>
                    <li class="todo"><?php echo $item['kategorie']; ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>   
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p>No todos</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The Variables look like this (print_r):

```
$kategorie:  [kategorie] => test [0] => test
$item: Array ( [id] => 4 [0] => 4 [name] => name [1] => name [done] => 0 [2] => 0 [kategorie] => test [3] => test ) 1
```

My Problem is that the outer `foreach` loop works but the inner one only runs once. So it echos all names of items where kategorie is equal to the current kategorie but all the folowing times there is just no output, but $items is not empty at any time. What am I missing?

Comment: After finishing (or before entering) the second loop, you'd have to rewind the query results (if possible... ). Better read all items into an array beforehand and use this array instead...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz the queries where executed at the top of the page and are stored in mentioned variables, why would I have to rewind the results or use a different array? Isn't that an array what I am looping over?

Comment: So maybe that's because there's no matching items?

Comment: You don't have an `else` statement, so of course it will only output when `$item["kategorie"] == $kategorie["kategorie"]`

Comment: @u_mulder No its not that. If I remove the if statement it also doesn't work

Comment: @miken32 Correct. And then it goes to next kategorie and should loop over the items again but it doesnt

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Doing the execute command after each outer loop again works but why? And isnt there a better solution?

Comment: Please clarify: is `$items` a query result or an array?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz require_once 'app/init.php';
    $itemsQuery = $db->prepare("
        SELECT id, name, done, kategorie FROM todo WHERE user_id = :user_id
    ");
    $itemsQuery->execute([
        'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']
    ]);

    $items = $itemsQuery->rowCount() ? $itemsQuery : []; That is the code of $items. I thought that was an array.

Comment: `$itemsQuery` is a statement object, not an array.

Comment: @miken32 but why can't I iterate over it several times why do I have to convert it to array or reload it

Comment: It depends on the cursor type used with the statement. A forward-only cursor can be iterated only once and not move backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, as provided, [works fine](https://3v4l.org/FsF9t):

```php
<?php

$kategorien = [
    ["kategorie" => "test"],
    ["kategorie" => "sample"],
];
$items = [
    ["id" => 1, "name" => "item1", "done" => 0, "kategorie" => "test"],
    ["id" => 2, "name" => "item2", "done" => 0, "kategorie" => "test"],
    ["id" => 3, "name" => "item3", "done" => 0, "kategorie" => "sample"],
    ["id" => 4, "name" => "item4", "done" => 0, "kategorie" => "test"],
    ["id" => 5, "name" => "item5", "done" => 0, "kategorie" => "sample"],
];
?>

<?php foreach($kategorien as $kategorie): ?>

<div class="list">
    <h1><?= $kategorie['kategorie'] ?></h1>
    <?php if(!empty($items)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
            <?php if($kategorie['kategorie'] == $item['kategorie']): ?>
        <li class="todo"><?= $item['name'] ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>No todos</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But in comments, we learned that `$items` is not an array, but a statement object. So you need to do this:

```php
<?php
require_once 'app/init.php';
$itemsQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, done, kategorie FROM todo WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$itemsQuery->execute(['user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id']]);
$items = $itemsQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And similar with your category list. Running `fetchAll()` saves the results into an array that can be looped over as many times as you like.

A database result set has an internal counter; once you've reached the end of the result set you can no longer loop over it, unlike an array.

Comment: Thank you very much that work :). But why do i have to do that? Why cant I loop over the Object multiple times, do you know that?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: You can work with a [scrollable cursor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#example-1101), but it's a lot of effort for no real purpose.